# MFC member variable type

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, mfc

I have MFC dialog that contains Edit Text control. With form wizard I have generated m_edit variable for this control. Variable type is CEdit. How to get string value from m_edit?

I found in some samples from internet that member variable might be CString type that looks more convenient for me. Unfortunately variable selection type is not enabled in form wizard and it is set to CEdit. How to make m_edit a CString type?

I need to use this member variable to get information from Edit Text control

Answer (score 0):

You can select it as a CString type during the wizard, but you should be careful to choose the type control/value, if you want it to be CString, you should choose Value type.

Comment: Fine, but how to ask wizard to copy Edit Text text to value type member variable? I need to use this member variable to get information from Edit Text control

Comment: @user1501700 try GetWindowText

Comment: @user1501700: You should read the documentation for `CWnd::UpdateData` and `CWnd::DoDataExchange`. The wizard will also add code to DoDataExchange so that the MFC framework keeps the CString and the dialog edit text in sync.

Answer (score 0):

In the `DoDataExchange` function what was been generated? I presume it was

```
DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_YOUR_EDIT_BOX, m_edit);
```

For the DDX_Control the 3rd parameter absolutely needs to be a CWnd-based type and CString is not.

If you want to get the text,

```
UpdateData();

CString s;
m_edit.GetWindowText(s);
```

Now the `s` variable has the text you want.

If you want to try it directly with a string, you can try to add a CString member variable to your class.

```
CString m_edit_string;
```

In your `DoDataExchange` function add:

```
DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_YOUR_EDIT_BOX, m_edit_string);
```

NB it is `DDX_Text`.

Wherever you need the text call `UpdateData();` and then the `m_edit_string` variable has the text.

Comment: `UpdateData` is not needed when you call `GetWindowText`. It is only needed if you want to update all non-window variables (CString, int, ...) associated to the control ID.